# How do you import the Average figure for the previous 7 days data from another Google Sheet document?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a Google Sheet document with each days sales figures on it. On a second Google Sheet document I need to have a dashboard which updates daily to show the average sales figures for the past 7 days. This needs to update daily so that it's always showing the previous 7 days but not include todays (for example if today is the 20th June, I want it to do the average for 13th-19th June).

How on earth do I go about creating this formula?

I know how to do an import range and the average formula but not how to select data based on the previous 7 days and not even the faintest idea how I create a formula that incorporates all 3 of these functions.

Each days date is in column A and the sales figures are in column B.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use QUERY formula.
First you enter your range using importrange,
then you select average of second column.
You set 2 conditions - date must be smaller or equal to yesterday (today()-1)
and date must be bigger than 8 days ago.
'label' clause is used to skip heading from query results.

```
=query(
importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYSa2pRl9n7AnFsn24DpMB9GKXgUnFQqVmBfNZVDsz0/edit#gid=0";"A:B");
"select avg(Col2) 
where Col1<= date '"&text(today()-1;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and 
Col1> date '"&text(today()-8;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
label avg(Col2) ''")
```

[image]

Here is working example:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYSa2pRl9n7AnFsn24DpMB9GKXgUnFQqVmBfNZVDsz0/edit#gid=0

Importrange is used within the same file just for illustration purposes. It can reffer to different document as well.

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I've managed to get this working but I'm having to duplicate data. The issue is that my dates are in actual fact in column B and my sales figures are in column M. I'm not sure how I go about setting this up as B:M clearly won't work.

Comment: O.K. You should set b:m range in your importrange and change Col1, Col2 etc. to corresponding numbers in your B:M range. B should be Col1 and Sales in Col12 (12th column of imported range).

Comment: You can also import ranges separately. Like this (instead of one importrange){importrange("url";"B:B"),importrange("url";"M:M")} . In this situation you don't have to change column numbers and stay with Col1,Col2.

Comment: I've tried your import ranges separately method as that would suit my issue cleaner. I'm only getting an error however.

=query({importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYSa2pRl9n7AnFsn24DpMB9GKXgUnFQqVmBfNZVDsz0/edit#gid=0";"B:B"),importrange("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TYSa2pRl9n7AnFsn24DpMB9GKXgUnFQqVmBfNZVDsz0/edit#gid=0";"M:M”)};"select avg(Col2) where Col1<= date '"&text(today()-1;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1> date '"&text(today()-8;"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'label avg(Col2) '’")

Comment: Ignore that last message, your other method worked perfectly!! Thanks!!

I presume the date format HAS to be yyyy-mm-dd and can't be dd-mm-yyyy ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach without concatenation and using the QUERY( scalar functions

```
=query(<import range>,"SELECT AVG(Col2) WHERE dateDiff(now(),Col1) < 8 AND dateDiff(now(),Col1) > 0 FORMAT AVG(Col2) '##0'", 1)
```

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage#scalar_functions